# Faster way to copy a cell value and send it to another spreadsheet via script (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wonder if there is a more simplified and faster model to send the value of a cell to another spreadsheet.

My actual script:

```
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Valores por Vantagem');
  var range = ss.getRange('F1');
  var data = range.getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Gerais');
  if(ts.getMaxRows() <= data.length) ts.insertRows(2, data.length);
  ts.getRange(268, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

Comment: Faster, but not simple is using [tag:google-sheets-api] directly through UrlfetchApp or through "Advanced Google services"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A more simplified solution would be the following.**

- Since you want to copy the value of **a single cell**, use `SetValue`
  instead of `SetValues` and change the range at the end:

  `var data = range.getValues()` => `var data = range.getValue()`.
- Also, replace:

  `ts.getRange(268, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data)`

  with:  `ts.getRange(268, 1).setValue(data)`.

  since data now is a single element.
- Finally, you can get rid of `if(ts.getMaxRows() <= data.length) ts.insertRows(2, data.length)`.

---

**Solution:**

```
function myFunction(){

var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Valores por Vantagem');
  var range = ss.getRange('F1');
  var data = range.getValue();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Gerais');      
  ts.getRange(268, 1).setValue(data);
}
```